# Integration testing Google Signin JWT id token with backend API

Tags: oauth, jwt, google-oauth, integration-testing, google-signin

I have an API that accepts google id tokens in the standard way [described here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth).

1. user opens Google oAuth popup and selects account
2. popup closes resolving with google id JWT
3. JWT is sent to my API `/login` or `/register` endpoint
4. backend decodes and verifies the JWT then uses the contained claims to register or log the user in accordingly.

I also have a suite of simple integration tests that run against the API including tests for whether it can register or log a user in using an email/password.

I'd like to write tests for whether `/login` and `/register` work correctly with google JWT but I can't think of a way given that JWT by design are only valid when signed by Google which I can't get in automated tests. My current ideas:

- config of some kind that skips JWT verification in dev/test mode - this would work but introducing a potential security vulnerability for the sake of a test feels like a code smell
- not testing :(

Any ideas?

Comment: The scope of what you're trying to test is unclear. Is your backend using Google client libraries to verify the token?

Comment: @identigral yes

Comment: Assuming you aren't interested in testing Google libs, simply mocking the lib to return claims based on your own JWT seems like a way to go.

Comment: Thanks - yeah I was trying to avoid mocking since they're integration tests.

Comment: Right. You might find Martin Fowler's classification of [broad vs narrow integration tests](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/IntegrationTest.html) helpful.